# PowerShell CSV Compare files with dynamic file names

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need to generate a comparison between two files from two generated reports. My issue is one generated report name changes based on the date it was generated. The last bit of the file date is in MMDDYY format as displayed below.

Pain points include : the modified date, last written date, creation date are all the same since I am staging the files into the server every time the script is run, then the files are deleted.

My goal is to run the comparison with the most up-to-date file. Is there a way to run a compare which of the these two files mentioned are the most recent?

[Name of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3LKI.png)

Comment: Yes you can definitely compare the dates. I feel like we need to see your code and have you explain exactly how it isn't doing what you want.

Comment: I dont have code to show involving this comparison between the old and the new file yet (in the image I have shown). I was hoping to get some ideas.

Comment: The common way to do it is something along the lines of: `Get-ChildItem .\*.xlsx | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Slect-Object -Last 1`

Comment: This appears to work! thank you